# I do not how stop my service

Tags: android, service

I have a problema with my service. I have 3 button, the first one call service in order to get numbers at randon and show them in a textbox every 10 second, the second button call service in order to get numbers at rand every I press that button and the last button must stop the service but I cannot when I press it and when I close the app and open again the service run automatically I do not understand!!

There is my service class

```
public class MyService extends Service{
public static final String NEW_DATA = "com.example.t8ej1.MyService.NEW_DATA";
private static final String stringUrl =
"http://www.imaginaformacion.com/recursos/rand.php";
private static final int updateInterval = 1000;
private Timer updateTimer;
private TimerTask doRefresh;
private String data;
public int service_id;
private IBinder binder = new MyBinder ();

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
MyService getService() {
return MyService.this;
}}

private void updateData() {
    // Nos conectamos al servicio web y obtenemos los datos

    try{

        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            data= reader.readLine();
            in.close();
            announceData();


        }

    } 

    catch( MalformedURLException e){
        Log.e("Service", e.getMessage());
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("Service", e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void announceData() {
    // Lanzamos el broadcast con el intent y los datos

    Intent intent = new Intent(NEW_DATA);
    intent.putExtra("data", data);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return binder;
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Creamos el Timer y el TimerTask

    service_id=startId;
    updateTimer = new Timer();
    doRefresh = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            updateData();
        }
    };
    // Lo programamos para que se lance cada updateInterval milisegundos
    updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doRefresh, 0, updateInterval);
    // Queremos que el servicio esté siempre encendido


    return Service.START_STICKY;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("mm", "4444");
    super.onDestroy();
}


public String getData() {
    return data;
    }}
```

There is my activity class

```
public class Service extends Activity {
private MyServiceReceiver myReceiver;
private MyService myService;
TextView txtManual;
TextView txtAuto;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);

    bindService(new Intent(Service.this, MyService.class),
            myConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    IntentFilter filter;
    filter = new IntentFilter(MyService.NEW_DATA);
    myReceiver = new MyServiceReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);


txtAuto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAuto);
txtManual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtManual);

Button cmdStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdStart);
Button cmdRefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdRefresh);
Button cmdStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdStop);

cmdStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        unbindService(myConnection);

        stopService(new Intent(Service.this, MyService.class));         


    }
});

cmdRefresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
    txtManual.setText(myService.getData());
    }
    });


cmdStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startService(new Intent(Service.this, MyService.class));
    }
});


}

    private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection () {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myService = ((MyService.MyBinder) service).getService();    
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myService=null;
        }


        };


public class MyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    txtAuto.setText(intent.getStringExtra("data")); 



    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override



protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
}}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int).  check bind and unbind http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**unbind service using** `unbindService()` in your `onStop()` of `MyService` class (**Your** `Service`),

and **then  call** `stopService` in `Service` class (**your** `Activity`)

Comment: unbind service using unbindService() in your onStop() of MyService class (Your Service)? You tell me that I must create a onStop methods?

Comment: no you need to override onStop() method, like onCreate() !  something like :  @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStop();
//unbind service here
 }

Comment: But Myservice.class only have onDestroy method to override!!

Comment: And what is the different to unbind in activity than service?

Comment: check docs  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection)

Comment: But in that case in little hard becasue service connection is in activity and OnDestroy method is in my service class...!!

Comment: I diid that...but the app continue to get numbers at random..service dont stop

Comment: startService in onCreate, bind in onStart and unbind in onStop/onDestroy.

Comment: Well the problem is the timer that update the data was still running.For that reason I stop that timer in stop button and the app work well but I do not understand If I stop the service the data must not be update Anyone explain me that?